# Area of an irregular $n$-gon

Tags: euclidean-geometry, area, polygons

Given the coordinates for the vertices of an irregular polygon, is there a formula to calculate its area?

For example, if the coordinates given are $(0,0), (0,5), (1,5), (1,1), (5,1), (5,0)$ then the area is $9$. Is there a formula which takes in arbitrary vertices and spits out their area?

Comment: Pick's theorem (if the vertices are all integer valued) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula): if a polygon has vertices $(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_n,y_n)$, then its (signed) area is given by
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i y_{i+1}-x_{i+1}y_i)
$$
where all index arithmetic is performed modulo $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem). It's not exactly what you described, but you should be able to use it to construct some sort of program which takes the vertices as input and outputs the area.